# Error usando validaciones

Tags: laravel-5

Veran quiero permitir que un usuario ingrese dinero en una variable 'saldo', para lo cual tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Ingresar dinero</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="saldo">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="dinero" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Dinero ingresado</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="dinero" type="number" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('dinero') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="dinero" value="{{ old('dinero') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('dinero'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('dinero') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Realizar ingreso
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

El cual sera utilizado en el siguiente metodo:

```
public function sumar(IngresoRequest $request){
    auth()->user()->saldo+=$request->dinero;
    auth()->user()->save();
    return redirect('/')->with('message',['success','Su ingreso se ha realizado con exito.']);
}
```

Y tambien tengo el fichero de validación IngresoRequest.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class IngresoRequest extends FormRequest{
    public function authorize(){
        return true;
    }

    public function messages(){
        return[
            'dinero.request'=>'Es obligatorio indicar cuanto dinero ingresa',
            'dinero.integer'=>'Error de formato',
            'dinero.min'=>'Debes incluir 10000€ como mínimo'
        ];
    }

    public function rules(){
        return[
            'dinero'=>'request|integer|min:10000'
        ];
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, a la mínima que intente realizar el ingreso, me topo con esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si utilizo un Request normal en vez de IngresoRequest si funciona, por lo que el error debe estar en este validador.
¿Alguien sabe que hago mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error es muy simple, estás pasando una validación que no existe:

```
public function rules(){
    return[
        'dinero'=>'request|integer|min:10000'
    ];
}
```

Debería de ser así:

```
public function messages(){
    return[
        'dinero.required'=>'Es obligatorio indicar cuanto dinero ingresa',
        'dinero.integer'=>'Error de formato',
        'dinero.min'=>'Debes incluir 10000€ como mínimo'
    ];
}

public function rules(){
    return[
        'dinero'=>'required|integer|min:10000'
    ];
}
```

Cambiar la palabra `request` por `required`

Comment: Así que en vez de 'request' era 'required'. Pues gracias, ahora si que ha funcionado. Es todo un engrollo que el sistema de informe de errores sea caca.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez pues de hecho ese error nunca me había salido y fue gracias al informe de error que supe que era "ValidateRequest does not exist" con esto supe que había un método de validación incorrecto, saludos.